# Optimizing distance between two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, math, optimization, least-squares

I have two vectors with coordinates, stored as a OpenCV's floating points:
a) *dstpoints* is a vector with OpenCV points - `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` (I have 162 points in my example, they are not changing),
b) *ppts* is also `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` and the same size as dstpoints:
`std::vector<cv::Point2f> ppts = project_keypoints(params, input);`
But *ppts* is dependent on two other vectors:
- *input* is 2*162=324 long and is not changing,
- *params* is 189 long and its values should be changed to get the minimal value of variable *suma*, something like this:

```
    double suma = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<dstpoints_size; i++)
    {
        suma += pow(dstpoints[i].x - ppts[i].x, 2);
        suma += pow(dstpoints[i].y - ppts[i].y, 2);
    }
```

I'm looking for *params* vector that will give me the smallest value of *suma* variable. Least squares algorithm seems to be a good option to solve it: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares
I tried dlib version:
http://dlib.net/dlib/optimization/optimization_least_squares_abstract.h.html#solve_least_squares
 but I'm afraid that  is not good for my case.
I think, my problem in dlib version is that for every different *params* vector I get different *ppts* vector, not only single value, and I don't know if *solve_least_squares* function from dlib can match my example.
I'm looking for C++ solution (probably with optimizers) that could help to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get that. Does `params` change the `suma` result? If so, how? or is it an output parameter?

Comment: Questions asking for library recommendations are considered off-topic on Stackoverflow

Comment: ```params``` is an input parameter. And it changes the value of ```suma``` result.

Comment: YOur problem is you have only 162 data points (dstpoints) but 189 parameters to be minimized. Your system is overdefined.

Comment: You should consider adding more details to your questions. You are asking to solve an equation depending on many variables that are unknown to the reader. All we can do with the information we have is: Try to use nonlinear least-squares solvers like Ceres. From the code, I guess you are doing camera calibration, am I right?

Comment: Please show what `project_keypoints` does.

Comment: I'm translating Python's version of 'page_dewarper' (https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html) into C++. Original repo is here: https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp/blob/master/page_dewarp.py  
```params``` vector contains information like: output rotation vector, output translation vector, coordinates of image keypoints. They are stored as normalized values (between -1 and +1). I can calculate ```params``` vector for original image and my problem is how to change elements of ```params```vector to get vector ```ppts``` that is as close as possible to vector ```dstpoints```.

Comment: I discovered Ceres few hours ago - http://ceres-solver.org/  I'll definitely check it tomorrow. It looks very promising.